# Animación CSS con cambios no progresivos

Tags: css, css3

Quiero crear una animación en un texto para que cambie de color varias veces (p.e. 4 veces en cada rotación: primero verde, luego rojo, luego azul, y finalmente naranja). Para eso estoy usando animaciones con `@keyframes`, pero me encuentro con un problema: la animación es de forma progresiva y yo **quiero que el cambio de color ocurra de golpe**:

```css
@keyframes cambiaColores {
  0% { color: green; }
  25% { color: red; }
  50% { color: blue; }
  75% { color: orange; }
  100% { color: orange; }
}

#miDiv {
  animation: infinite cambiaColores linear 10s;
}
```

```html
<div id="miDiv">Texto que cambia de colores</div>
```

Pensé en poner porcentajes duplicados (0% -> verde, 25% -> verde, 25% -> rojo...), pero no funciona porque parece que si hay más de un porcentaje igual, ignora el primero y sólo ejecuta el último. Esto lo puedo solucionar poniendo decimales:

```css
@keyframes cambiaColores {
  0% { color: green; }
  24.999% { color: green; }
  25% { color: red; }
  49.999% { color: red; }
  50% { color: blue; }
  74.999% { color: blue; }
  75% { color: orange; }
  100% { color: orange; }
}

#miDiv {
  animation: infinite cambiaColores linear 10s;
}
```

```html
<div id="miDiv">Texto que cambia de colores</div>
```

Pero parece un poco engorroso, especialmente cuando la animación require más de sólo 4 cambios. ¿Existe alguna manera de decirle al navegador que cada paso de la animación debe hacerlo de golpe en lugar de de manera progresiva?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Utiliza [`step-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/single-transition-timing-function#step-end) en lugar de `linear` en el parámetro [timing function](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function).

> The animation stays in its initial state until the end, at which point
>   it jumps directly to its final state...
>
> **TRADUCCIÓN**
>
> La animación permanece en su estado inicial hasta el final,
>   en cuyo punto, salta directamente hasta el estado final...

```css
@keyframes cambiaColores {
  0% { color: green; }
  25% { color: red; }
  50% { color: blue; }
  75% { color: orange; }
  100% { color: orange; }
}

#miDiv {
  animation: infinite cambiaColores step-end 10s;
}
```

```html
<div id="miDiv">Texto que cambia de colores</div>
```

Comment: Genial. Es exactamente lo que buscaba. Simple y funcional.

Comment: De nada! Si te digo la verdad yo también lo acabo de descubrir! Saludos!